# Branding ribbon and top link navigation

Tags: 2010, master-page, ribbon, branding, top-link-bar

I'm working on a project in **SharePoint 2010**. The graphic designer developed styles to the top of the pages of SharePoint, which includes:

- Ribbon
- Title and icon
- Top link navigation

Graphic design includes:
- Background image
- Position change of title, logo and top link navigation

Important: I want to maintain the functionality of the ribbon

What is the recommended way to change the styles of that section?

Comment: There are many tutorials, blogs available online on how to customize header and navigation for SharePoint 2010.

Comment: Any recommendation?

Comment: You can find some in my answer

Comment: I will check...

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at the three part series on how to customize Top Navigation:

[Customizing SharePoint 2010 global navigation with Css and jQuery – Part 1](https://chrisstahl.wordpress.com/2010/11/04/customizing-sharepoint-2010-global-navigation-with-css-and-jquery-2/)

Here is another great series on how to brand SharePoint 2010:

[Brand SharePoint: Global Navigation – The Journey Begins (Part 3)](http://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/2012/04/27/brand-sharepoint-global-navigation-the-journey-begins-aspx/)

For the header like title and icon, you can create your own HTML instead using SharePoint's and place them as you like. The ribbon will be intact so you don't touch ribbon control in the Master page. Let me know if you need a sample master page.